# Wait with sending callback until variable is set

Tags: javascript

I want to wait with sending a callback until a variable is set;

Se my code:

```
function getNick(callback) {
    callback(nickName);
}
```

The nickName variable is not being set until later down in the code..

Is this possible?

Comment: It's an AJAX related issue or something else? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: What function sets the nickName variable? Could you wait to call `getNick` until after `nickName` is set?

Comment: Cant wait to call getNick unfornunatley

Answer (score 1):

You may be better of changing your code, but I guess you could store the callback function to a variable, and then call it later in your code (after the nickName is set)

Something like this

```
var nickSetCallback;

function getNick(callback){
   nickSetCallback = callback;
}


// .. More code ..

nick = "something";

if(nickSetCallback !== undefined)
   nickSetCallback(nick);
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Sorry, updated with code example..

Comment: @Alosyius: In that case, please check the <<< checkmark on the left of  this answer, to indicate this was the correct answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

This smells very much like bad code. But you can do it using a timer.

```
function getNick(callback) {
    if(typeof nickName !== undefined) {
        callback(nickName);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(getNick.bind(this, callback), 10);
    }
}
```

However, a cleaner way would be to use e.g. something like jQuery's `Deferred` object where you add the callback and then trigger it when setting the nickname.

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like Knockout or Reactive Extensions which provides mechanisms to observe data.

Here's how you'd do it in knockout:

```
var nickName = ko.observable();
function getNick(callback) {
    if (nickName()) {
       callback(nickName());
    }
    else {
       var d = nickName.subscribe(function (n) {
           callback(n);
           d.dispose();
       });
    }
};

// ...
getNick(function (value) { ... });
nickName("bannannas");
```